# .bat file which appends text at each line in a .txt, including part of the line itself

Tags: batch-file, text-files, edit

I need to create some `.cbc` files to use with Calibre. They are basically renamed to `.zip` files containing each chapter in another `.zip` and a text file named `comics.txt`, which points to each filename and gives it a chapter name for the TOC.

I have already automatized most of the process with a bunch of .bat files. However there is an annoyance I have no idea how to start fixing.

The text file needs the following format for each line:

```
[Filename of zip containing chapter].zip:Chapter xxx
```

For example:

```
Serie name c015 v03.zip:Chapter 15
Serie name c016 v03.zip:Chapter 16
Serie name c016.1 v03.zip:Chapter 16.1
```

For this specific part of the process I am using the following .bat:

```
dir /b *.zip > comic.txt
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (comic.txt) do @echo %%i:Chapter )>comics.txt
del comic.txt
start comics.txt
```

This adds `:Chapter` to the end of each line, saving me part of the work. However, I still need to add the chapter name manually, that's why I outright open the file at the end.

Is there any way for the .bat to "take" text from each filename and add it after ":Chapter ", so instead of getting

```
Serie name c015 v03.zip:Chapter 
Serie name c016 v03.zip:Chapter 
Serie name c016.1 v03.zip:Chapter
```

I outright get:

```
Serie name c015 v03.zip:Chapter 15 
Serie name c016 v03.zip:Chapter 16 
Serie name c016.1 v03.zip:Chapter 16.1
```

Comment: You need to define the criteria for how to extract the chapter number; do the file names always end with `c`, followed by the chapter number, a space, `v` and another number? What have you tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: All `.zip` do have the string `cxxx` somewhere in the filename. As to solve it myself, I truly don't know how to even begin. Most of the other `.bat` I use for this process just requiered minor tweaks to adapt to my needs, but searching the file name for a string, removing the needless characters and appending it to a `.txt` line by line proved harder than I could manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably accomplish your task with the following script (let us call it `extract-chapter-numbers.bat`). This expects the chapter part (`c`, followed by something numeric) as the last or the next-to-last space-separated token in the `.zip` file names; if it is the next-to-last one, the last one is expected to be `v`, followed by something numeric (if that part could be anything, just replace the line `set "_FILTER_V=v[0-9\.][0-9\.]*"` in the script by `set "_FILTER_V=.*"`).

So here is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=."                    & rem // (directory containing the files to process)
set "_FILTER_C=c[0-9\.][0-9\.]*" & rem // (`findstr` expression for the chapter part)
set "_FILTER_V=v[0-9\.][0-9\.]*" & rem // (`findstr` expression for the version part)
set "_FILTER_E=zip"              & rem // (`findstr` expression for the file extension)
set "_PREFIX=Chapter"            & rem // (string to precede the chapter number with)

rem /* Loop through all matching files that contain a chapter number (preceded by `c`)
rem    and an optional version code preceded by `v`): */
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "%_ROOT%\* c*.%_FILTER_E%" ^| findstr /I /R /E ^
        /C:"..*  *%_FILTER_C%  *%_FILTER_V%\.%_FILTER_E%" ^
        /C:"..*  *%_FILTER_C%\.%_FILTER_E%" ^
') do (
    rem // Store current file name, reset some variables:
    set "LINE=%%J" & set "LAST=" & set "NEXT="
    rem /* Loop through all space-separated parts of the base file name
    rem    (note that `,`, `;`, `=` are also treated as separators): */
    for %%I in (%%~nJ) do (
        rem // Store the last and the next-to-last parts:
        call set "NEXT=%%LAST%%" & set "LAST=%%I"
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Check whether the last or the next-to-last part begins with `c`, and if so,
    rem    extract the following numeric part: */
    if /I "!LAST:~,1!"=="c" (
        set "CHPT=!LAST:~1!"
    ) else if /I "!NEXT:~,1!"=="c" (
        set "CHPT=!NEXT:~1!"
    ) else (
        set "CHPT="
    )
    rem // Return the original file name, together with a prefix and chapter number:
    if defined CHPT echo(!LINE!:!_PREFIX! !CHPT!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

If you run it from the directory containing your sample files:

> ```cmd
> Serie name c015 v03.zip
> Serie name c016 v03.zip
> Serie name c016.1 v03.zip
> ```

The output will be:

> ```cmd
> Serie name c015 v03.zip:Chapter 015
> Serie name c016 v03.zip:Chapter 016
> Serie name c016.1 v03.zip:Chapter 016.1
> ```

To store this in a text file (say `comics.txt`), run the script like this:

```cmd
extract-chapter-numbers.bat > comics.txt
```

Comment: I'm actually interested here, Is `[0-9\.]` a valid use of `find`? This is a way to dynamically find a number? As in example `c015` if we use `find /I c[0-9\.][0-9\.]5` it will look for `cXX5` (X is variable can be any single#) in statement?

Comment: @JohnKens, you need to use the [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command, which has got a basic regular expression support, but not [`find`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html), which can only search for literal strings. `[0-9\.]` defines a character class: a decimal digit or a dot...

Answer (score 2):

The only challenge is to find the chapter number. It helps that it always start with `<space>c`

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM following two lines to create test environment:
for /l %%a in (14,1,20) do break>"The Hulk The Beginning c0%%a v03.zip"
break>"The Hulk The Beginning c016.1 v03.zip"
(
REM for every .zip file:
for %%a in (*.zip) do (
  for %%b in (%%~na) do ( 
   REM find a token which starts with 'c' and at least one number:
   echo %%b|findstr /b "c[0-9][0-9]*" >nul && set chapter=%%b
  )
  echo %%~nxa:Chapter !chapter:~1!
))>comics.txt
```